# JS Array problem in implementing shopping cart

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and i'm working on a project where I need to implement a simple shopping cart using JavaScript.

Im fetching the products from the database using PHP and displaying them using this code:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 item">
            <?php
            $return = $dbObject ->getProduce('fruits', 3);

            foreach( $return as $key =>$row){
                $id = $row['produce_id'];
                $stock = $row['produce_available'];
                $name = $row['produce_name'];
                $unit = $row['produce_unit'];
                $price = $row['produce_unit_price'];
                $imgName = $row['produce_image_name'];
                $imgFolder = $row['produce_image_folder'];

                ?>

                <script>
                    var key = itemKey();
                </script>

                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4' >
                        <div class='thumbnail'>
                            <p style='visibility : ' id = 'itemId'><?php echo $id; ?></p>
                            <p style='visibility : hidden' id = 'itemStock'><?php echo $stock; ?></p>
                            <p class='text-center' id = "itemName"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                            <img src='admin/<?php echo $imgFolder ."/".$imgName; ?>'>
                            <div class='caption'>
                                <p>kshs. <span id = 'itemPrice'><?php echo $price; ?> </span> /= per <span id = 'itemUnit'><?php echo $unit; ?></span>
                                <button class='btn pull-right' class = 'cartBtn' id = '' onclick = 'display(addToCart(key))'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span></button></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </div>
```

This is the JS code that should be executed when the 'Add to Cart' Button is clicked:

```
var cart = [];

        function addToCart(item){
            var id = $("#itemId").text();
            var name = $("#itemName").text();
            var stock = $("#itemStock").text();
            var unit = $("#itemUnit").text();
            var price = $("#itemPrice").text();


                var cartItem = {
                    cartItemId : id,
                    cartItemName : name,
                    cartItemStock : stock,
                    cartItemUnit : unit,
                    cartItemPrice : price,
                }

                cart.push(cartItem);
                console.log(cart);
                return cart;
            }

        function itemKey(){
            var key;
            key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000001);
            return key;
        }


        function checkIfInCart(item){
            //check if item is in cart
            var inCart = false;
            if(cart.includes(item) == true){
                inCart = true;
            }
            else{
                incart = false;
            }

        return inCart;
        }


        function display(){
            for(i = 0; i < cart.length; i ++){
                $("#cartContents").html("<tr><td></td><td>" + cart[i].cartItemName + "</td><td></td><td>" + cart[i].cartItemPrice + "</td><td></td></tr>");
            }
        }
```

It works fine, except that the array only accepts only one item and the if you click the button to push() another item to the cart array, it only duplicates the first item already in the cart. 
The console.log for the output looks like this:

```
 (1) […]
​
0: Object { cartItemId: "4", cartItemName: "Apples", cartItemStock: "200", … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []

​
0: Object { cartItemId: "4", cartItemName: "Apples", cartItemStock: "200", … }
​
1: Object { cartItemId: "4", cartItemName: "Apples", cartItemStock: "200", … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []

(3) […]
​
0: Object { cartItemId: "4", cartItemName: "Apples", cartItemStock: "200", … }
​
1: Object { cartItemId: "4", cartItemName: "Apples", cartItemStock: "200", … }
​
2: Object { cartItemId: "4", cartItemName: "Apples", cartItemStock: "200", … }
​
length: 3
```

How can I ensure that the Cart accepts a second and third.... items added instead of duplicating the first?

Comment: You're outputting `var key = itemKey();` in your PHP loop. That's not going to work. PHP and JS don't run side-by-side. Similarly, you cannot have the same `id` multiple times. `var id = $("#itemId").text();` is going to grab the very first `id="itemId"` it finds, ignoring the rest (how is it supposed to find the right one anyway?).

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/s82r5g13/ The first item is what goes in your PHP loop, the second is example output. Check the console to see the full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which gives unique elements in an array, This will avoid the problem of duplicate elements

`
//Filter Unique Values
const array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 1];

const uniqueArray = [...new Set(array)];

console.log(uniqueArray);`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: the foreach loop in PHP will render multiple `#itemId` elements into DOM and you are querying always for the first one

---

You are not using the `item` argument in `addToCart(item)` nor you are setting it to a unique value that would represent a specific item:

```
...
var key = itemKey(); // this always generates a unique value, it doesn't point to the current $row item rendered in the PHP context
...
onclick = 'display(addToCart(key))' // here you are just passing that random value to the add function
...
```

And in the function itself you are querying for the first item in the DOM that matches the ID (always the first one) instead of a specific item's dom element:

```
...
function addToCart(item){
            var id = $("#itemId").text(); // this will always choose the first #itemId element in DOM
            var name = $("#itemName").text();
            var stock = $("#itemStock").text();
            var unit = $("#itemUnit").text();
            var price = $("#itemPrice").text();
...
```

There are multiple ways to solve it the easier one being to add another unique identifier (per product) into the dom so you can select name (and the other properties) of a specific product:

```
<div class='thumbnail' id='product-<?php echo $id; ?>'> // added a per-product DOM element ID #product-X
```

Then you need to pass that it in the click handler:

```php
...
onclick = 'display(addToCart("#product-<?php echo $id; ?>"))' // passing that id to the add function
...
```

Now you can change your queries like so:

```
...
function addToCart(item){
            var id = $(item + " #itemId").text(); // now the query will find the correct element
            var name = $(item + " #itemName").text();
            var stock = $(item + " #itemStock").text();
            var unit = $(item + " #itemUnit").text();
            var price = $(item + " #itemPrice").text();
...
```

Also please note that it is not exactly clean to have the same element ID multiple times on one page and I would recommend to use classes instead.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried your suggestion and the cart array returns empty values i.e no items are pushed into the array. My question is whether its correct to pass the argument of addToCart() function as `onclick = 'display(addToCart("#product-<?php echo $id; ?>"))' ` like you have shown in your code. Also can u clarify `var id = $(item + " #itemId").text();` . Thanks

Comment: @Vic You need to pass the product id from PHP into the Javascript "context". By printing the ID in PHP you can pass that value as a Javascript string containing the element ID of the product thumbnail element. Then you can just use that ID as a selector inside jQuery